# Why is my git bash (mingw64) running a nonsense command when using the -c option?

Tags: windows, command-line, bash, git, mingw

I am getting this at the moment when using git bash:

```
C:\>bash -c pwd
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe: line 1: $'MZ\220\003': command not found
/c
```

When I use the debbuging option, I get this:

```
C:\>bash -x -c pwd
+ $'MZ\220\003'
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe: line 1: $'MZ\220\003': command not found
+ pwd
/c
```

What is causing this additional `$'MZ\220\003'` command to be executed?

This is my scenario:

- Installed git bash from https://git-scm.com/download/win
- Added "C:\Program Files\Git\bin" to my path, above "Windows\System32" to override the bash in there
- I can confirm that bash from my cmd session is using the git version
- I cannot see any .bashrc,.profile or .bash_login entry that could be adding in this command
- I have another sperate Windows machine with the same setup and the command works fine there

Comment: About `MZ`: [DOS MZ executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS_MZ_executable). It may be a coincidence `MZ` appears in the error message you got; or not.

Comment: `MZ` is also used for Windows executables (...and UEFI executables), so it's probably that an .exe got accidentally copied _to_ .bashrc, or is being `source`d out of .bashrc – use Sysinternals Process Monitor to find out what files are being loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the issue. Not sure if this will ever be of use to anyone else, but I will post my findings.

In my windows environment variables I had mistakenly set the BASH_ENV to the path of the bash exe that I was using (C:\Program files\Git\bin\bash.exe). So I think what was happening was:

1. I run the command `bash -c pwd` in cmd
2. cmd finds the git bash exe
3. git bash exe runs and tries to load vars from BASH_ENV
4. It finds a path to itself tries to run it?

Weird thing was it actually tried to look for an executable called `MZ* .exe` in a number of different directories before erroring out. Proc mon shows:

[Process monitor screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6xgY.png)

Also probing the environment, the bash exe showed:

`_=$$'MZ\220\003'`

Not sure at to the inner workings here, but ultimately deleting that env var solved my issues and I can finally use it as normal (whew...)